# Is it possible to intercept a request and force login to my website?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a website and I created this login verification function, but I would like to know if any user intercepted this request and changed the response to true they could gain access.

```
  url: "auth/login.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: {
    "usuario": usuario, 
    "senha": senha, 
    "g-recaptcha-response": response
  },
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(retorno){
    
    $("#btn_login").text("ACESSAR");
    $("#btn_login").attr("disabled", false);
    
  if(retorno.success == true){
    Swal.fire({title:"Sucesso:", icon: "success", text: "Usuario Logado", toast: true, position: "top-end", showConfirmButton: false, timer: 3000});
    setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.href = "dashboard/index.php";
    }, 3000);
    
  }else{
    Swal.fire({title:"Erro: ", icon:"error", text:retorno["message"], toast: true, position: "top-end", showConfirmButton:false, timer: 3000});
          }
        }
      }); //ajax
```

Comment: They don't need to intercept and manipulate anything, they just need to visit *dashboard/index.php*. If your website is properly secured **by the backend code**, that  won't "grant them access" to anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you directly access the **"dashboard/index.php"** route, what will happen?

You just do the redirect with this code, or you do something in the backend that saves the **"logged"** status?

regardless of these questions, anyone that intercept your response and change the "retorno" to true, will be redirected to **"dashboard/index.php"**

Comment: Please keep your whole answer in English, as Stack Overflow is an [English-only site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/non-english-questions). Adding a translation in a second language doesn't really help and will very likely only be seen as noise to future visitors (considering, as said before, this is an English-only site and most people on here primarily speak English.).

Comment: @Jesse i undestood, all my next answers will be whole in English.